# change "speed" for few seconds

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, timer

So I have an object that moves with "speed" now I set the code that when the object collides with another object the speed of the object decreases. I tried doing so by making the speed change and when the speed changes after 3 seconds change it back to it's original speed.

This is something I tried myself but it doesn't work. Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong, if I'm on the right track or a better way to do this? Thanks in advance

```
 speed = 10;

 if (c < r0+r1) { 
 lives -=1;

 speed = 5;

 if(speed === 5){
    setTimeout(speed =10 ,3000);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    speed = 10 
}, 3000);
```

Comment: tried this but when I use this code the object waits 3 seconds before the speed changes and doesn't change back. I'm trying that when the object collides the speed changes for 3 seconds and after that changes back to it's original speed. Thanks for the reaction !

Comment: @NickZijlstra your problem must be in another part of your code, this will return speed to 10 after 3 seconds

Comment: you are absolutely right I forgot deleted the speed = 5 so there was no change. Thanks a lot !